# TimeZoneInfo works differently in two bits of code

Tags: c#, timezone

I have some code in my UI layer, which is supposed to take a DateTime, which is in UTC, and convert it to a local date time:

In my Data layer, I simply do this:

```
private DateTime ConvertToLocal(DateTime dt)
{
    if (_currentTimeZoneUser == string.Empty)
    {
        var u = new UserData(_userId).GetUser(_userId);
        _currentTimeZoneUser = u.TimeZoneId;
    }
    var reply = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dt, _currentTimeZoneUser);
    return reply;
}
```

What that does is check if _currentTimeZoneUser is set. If not, get the zimezone from the user table, and then does a conversion.

This code is working, and I get a valid result.

I then copied the code to my UI layer (As I need to do a conversion there as well, for a data grid), but 'reply' always equals 'dt'.

I googled, and noticed that I should be doing it a slightly different way. So I change my UI method to this:

```
public static DateTime GetLocalDateTime(DateTime serverTime)
{
    var timeZoneId = HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeZoneId"].ToString();
    TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    var reply = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(serverTime, cstZone);
    return reply;
}
```

and it works!

I can't see why it works in my data layer, but in the UI, I need to change the code.

Am I doing something wrong with my time conversion code in one of the methods?

Comment: This is all rather wrong-headed.  When you work with HttpContext then the *only* entity interested in the local time is the user, several thousands of miles and an unguessable number of time zones removed from your web server.  Strictly work with UTC on the server end, convert to local time in the browser.

Comment: @HansPassant - That requires JavaScript, which isn't always possible, and has bugs in this area [when converting past dates](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/).  There's nothing wrong with doing time zone conversions in server-side code, as long as you know the user's time zone id, which he does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, your question boils down to the difference between `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` and `ConvertTimeFromUtc`.

First, you need to understand that any time zone conversion operations involving `DateTime` may have behavioral differences depending on the value of the `.Kind` of `DateTime` you are giving it.  When you look at the documentation for each of these methods ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396328.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx)), you will find a chart that describes the behavior for each of the three different kinds (`Utc`,`Local`, and `Unspecified`).

This is a sore point in .Net, which is why libraries like [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) exist.  You can read more in these two articles:

- [What's wrong with DateTime Anyway?](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html)
- [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)

The actual reason for the specific problem is that you probably passed in a `DateTime` who's `.Kind` is `Unspecified`.  In the `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` method, that will be treated as if it were `Local`, while in the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method it will be treated as if it were `Utc`.

There are two solutions.

- The first is what you already found - use the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method.  You should do this in the server code also.
- The second solution is to set the `.Kind` to `Utc` when you load the value from your database.  Somewhere you probably have code like this:

  ```
  foo.MyDateTime = (DateTime) dataReader["MyDateTime"]
  ```

  Which would change to this:

  ```
  foo.MyDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
                     (DateTime) dataReader["MyDateTime"],
                     DateTimeKind.Utc);
  ```

I'm assuming you are doing a direct ADO.Net call with a `DataReader` response.  Adjust accordingly for whatever you are actually doing.